# Array find the number of same element

Tags: arrays, ruby

For example I have an array such as this:

```
["a","a","a","a","b","c","d","a","a","a"] #Expected result = 4
```

How can I find the number of same element, in my case `"a"`, before it change to different value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maintain 2 pointers (prev and current) and iterate through the array comparing those two pointers.

Comment: If your array were `arr = ["b","b","a","a","a","b","a"]` and the first run of `"a"` were to be counted, the answer would be `3`. Correct? If so, it would be better if your array didn't begin with `"a"`, as that has led to confusion. Incidentally, when you give an example, assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = ["a","a"....`), so that readers can refer to the variable in answers and comments without having to define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def nbr_consecutive(arr, str)
  start_ndx = arr.index(str)
  return 0 if start_ndx.nil?
  a = arr[start_ndx..-1]      
  a.index { |s| s != str } || a.size
end

arr = %w| e e a a a a b c d a a a |
  #=> ["e", "e", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a", "a"]

nbr_consecutive(arr, "e")
  #=> 2
nbr_consecutive(arr, "a")
  #=> 4
nbr_consecutive(arr, "b")
  #=> 1
nbr_consecutive(arr, "z")
  #=> 0
```

Comment: Did your letter store run out of vowels? :-P

Comment: @Jörg, yes, I shipped all I had to Eastern Europe, where there's a tremendous shortage.

Answer (score 1):

```
letters = ["a","a","a","a","b","c","d","a","a","a"]
letters.take_while { |letter| letter == letters.first }.count
 => 4
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question.  My reading is that If the value to be matched were `"b"`, the count would be 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = ["a","a","a","a","b","c","d","a","a","a"]
```

If you only care about the first value, no matter what it is:

```
p array.slice_when(&:!=).first.size #=> 4

# same as array.slice_when{|x,y| x != y }.first.size #=> 4
```

If you need to look for a specific value:

```
p array.slice_when(&:!=).find{|x| x.first == 'b' }.size #=> 1
```

Or perhaps:

```
p array.slice_when(&:!=).to_a.assoc('a').size #=> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most Ruby-ish way I could think of

```
list.drop_while { |letter| letter != letter_to_find }.take_while { |letter| letter == letter_to_find }.count
```

The idea is to remove the letters in the beginning until you find the letter you want and then count the letters that you want until you reach a letter that is not your letter.

So for you example you would do

```
["a","a","a","a","b","c","d","a","a","a"].drop_while { |letter| letter != "a" }.take_while { |letter| letter == "a" }.count
```

Not that only `take_while` is necessary for your specific example but `drop_while` is necessary if you have letters preceding the letters you want.

Answer (score -2):

```
array = ["a","a","a","a","b","c","d","a","a","a"]

array.chunk{|char| char}.map{|char, a| a.size if char == "a"}.first
```

Comment: Thanks but my expected result is '4' because it will only calculate the first four 'a' until it change to 'b'.

Comment: If you add a different letter to this, the count will be 5 instead of 4.  It's only coincidentally 4 because there are four unique letters in the list.

Comment: Do you want to find count of the given element? for example "a" means, it should return 7 ?

Comment: ...Did you not, like, read the question or something?  I don't want to sound rude, but the question is clearly asking for the count of consecutive characters.

Comment: @Makoto got it now.. Thanks

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.